# Ender 3 s1 Pro, Cura, and Bondtech CHT 0.4 mm nozzle

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, extrusion, klipper

So I swapped the standard Ender 3 S1 Pro 0.4 mm nozzle to a Bondtech CHT 0.4 mm nozzle to increase my flow rate, but I am a newb and not really sure what to do to start dialing this in.

I have not been able to get any adherence to my bed since making the nozzle change. I have not as of yet changed my Cura / Sonic Pad settings from the standard 0.4 mm nozzle, but before moving to the CHT I was printing PLA fine, so I am confident it's dialing in my settings for this nozzle.

Any links or info would be a great help so I can figure out where to start. Even better if anyone has made this change a profile would be killer! I'm just starting to research this and teach myself, but would really appreciate any and all assistance. Not including my settings, as I do not think my wrong stuff will help, but I can upload them in the morning if people feel it is helpful.

Comment: Did you check the distance between the nozzle and the heated bed after the change? You need to re-check the Z-offset when you change the nozzle.

Comment: Multiple times, re-leveled it manually and the auto level. Didn't help which is why I was thinking it was related to the flow rate. Oddly enough my test line down the side of the bed goes on fine as does some of the first layer, then other portions just do not.

Comment: Can you add a photograph ad the failed adhering print?

Comment: Just coming back to this. I can not, I have since switched it back from the bondtech nozzole to a standard one and sold the printer. Thanks for trying to assist me and sorry I have overlooked replying more quickly.

Comment: The nozzle is 0.5 mm shorter, so you need to adjust accordingly.